# Query to update multiple rows based counting up seconds from column in each row

Tags: php, mysql

I want to run a query on MySQL that updates a certain number of rows based on a column in the table.

So, I have a column for `seconds` which is an integer and contains the number of seconds for a phone call for each row and a "max value" which is the maximum included for a single customer.

So we want to update the rows in the table setting the column `inclusive` to "1" up to the maximum value for the customer from the SUM of the `seconds` column.

I could write the query using PHP like this:

```
$max_value = 100;
$curr_val = 0;
$sql = $mysqli->query(SELECT * FROM tbl;");
while($result = $sql->fetch_array()) {
    if($curr_val >= $max_value) {
        break;
    }

    $mysqli->query("UPDATE tbl SET inclusive = '1' WHERE sequence = '".$result["sequence"]."';");
    
    $curr_value += $result["seconds"];
}
```

BUT, I wonder whether it's possible in a single query instead of using loops in PHP as this table is fairly large in size.

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result

Comment: @Jens I will add some examples, but I don't think much data is needed?

Comment: I can't say it. It hould be enough data to show us, how the input looks like and wat the output should be

Comment: @Jens see update, hows that?

Answer (score 1):

This example assumes that `sequence` is an ever-increasing integer PK. We can use SUM as a window function to calculate a running total up until the previous row.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        sequence,
        IFNULL(SUM(seconds) OVER (
            ORDER BY sequence
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
        ), 0) prev_cum_total
    FROM tbl
)
UPDATE tbl
JOIN cte ON tbl.sequence = cte.sequence
SET tbl.inclusive = 1
WHERE cte.prev_cum_total < 100;
```

If you need to do this allowing for grouping by a customer_id you can add PARTITION BY to the OVER clause -

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        sequence,
        IFNULL(SUM(seconds) OVER (
            PARTITION BY customer_id
            ORDER BY sequence
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
        ), 0) prev_cum_total
    FROM tbl
)
UPDATE tbl
JOIN cte ON tbl.sequence = cte.sequence
SET tbl.inclusive = 1
WHERE cte.prev_cum_total < 100;
```